# ORACLE Query: Select Text when value has "/" in the name

Tags: regex, oracle, special-characters

I need to select items in  a table when they match the following criteria:

1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS (A)  or  1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS (B)

But DOES NOT MATCH 3/4-1 TON TRUCK W/TOOLS or any other combination.

I've tried using wildcards.

```
Select *
FROM Table
WHERE UNIT_ID LIKE '1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS (A)'
```

This does not work. The only thing that seems to work is using '%Tools'. Unfortunately this pulls in other records that I do not want.

I've also tried using REGEX

```
WHERE regexp_like (unit_id, ' ^ (1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS) ')
```

Comment: May be you misspelled TRCK? Try using TRUCK..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a wildcard in your example though, it should be

```
Select *
FROM Table
WHERE UNIT_ID LIKE '1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS (%)'
```

Like won't work without a % or _

Comment: that would not work if a string is e.g. like '1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS x' it should only be matched with (A) and (B)

Comment: only (A) and (B) or some other things you haven't mentioned yet? If the former then the IN clause above will work fine

Comment: This worked. I assumed it was choking on the "/". As HotFix mentioned it does not capture the following characters but in my case this is acceptable.

Comment: I would prefer to use the IN command or REGEX but they do not seem to accept wildcards

Comment: But I thought you also needed it to match `'3/4-1 TON TRUCK W/TOOLS'`? By the way, only `like` accepts wildcards `%` and `_`. The `regexp_` functions use [regex syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_regexp.htm).

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of beating a dead horse, you can use regexp_like, just escape the parenthesis as they have special meaning in the regex 'language' and use the pipe symbol for an OR. This regex specifically looks for an 'A' or a 'B' character (denoted by the square brackets) inside of literal parenthesis.

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
     select '1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS (A)' from dual union all
     select '1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS (B)' from dual union all
     select '3/4-1 TON TRUCK W/TOOLS'  from dual
   )
   select str
   from tbl
   where regexp_like(str, '1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS \([A|B]\)');

STR
------------------------
1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS (A)
1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS (B)

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
FROM Table
WHERE UNIT_ID in('1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS (A)', '1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS (B)')
```

Comment: pls add some explanation to the query to have better understanding : Review

Answer (score 0):

REGEX does work if I include a wildcard for the parenthesis around the A

```
WHERE regexp_like (unit_id, '(1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS.A.)')
```

or

```
WHERE UNIT_ID LIKE '1/2 TON TRCK W/TOOLS (%)'
```

as kayakpim pointed out